# Using worker_threads to loop through array of 300k items and run tests with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, worker-thread

I have never used Workers with node before, but I have to run a series of tests with Jest with a large array of objects with size 300k+ items.

I'd like to run workers with subportions of this array and run the tests on each portion. How can I go about that?

UPDATE: code I'm using

```
const CPUS_NUMBER_LIMIT = os.cpus().length - 2;

const splitArray = (arr: any[]) => {
  return new Promise(async (parentResolve, parentReject) => {
    const segmentSize = Math.ceil(arr.length / CPUS_NUMBER_LIMIT);
    const segments = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < CPUS_NUMBER_LIMIT; index++) {
      const start = index * segmentSize;
      const end = start + segmentSize;
      const segment = arr.slice(start, end);
      segments.push(segment);
    }

    // Create a worker for each segment
    try {
      const results = await Promise.all(
        segments.map(
          (seg) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const worker = new Worker(
                `require('ts-node/register');
                require(require('worker_threads').workerData.runThisFileInTheWorker);`,
                {
                  eval: true,
                  workerData: {
                    runThisFileInTheWorker: path.join(process.cwd(), "./src/common/dump/worker.ts"),
                    seg,
                  },
                }
              );
              worker.on("message", parentResolve);
              worker.on("error", reject);
              worker.on("exit", (code) =>
                code !== 0 ? reject(new Error("Error with code" + code)) : {}
              );
            })
        )
      );
    } catch (error) {
      parentReject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples/tutorials on the web for using workerThreads in nodejs.  What code did you try and where did you get stuck?  You can slice your array into pieces and pass each worker a piece of the array for it to process.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was not able to find that many tutorials. Currently I am splitting the array into chunks then starting a loop for each segment and I create a worker (the documentation says to use a pool of worker but I couldn't find how to create such pool)

However from what I understand each worker will receive a copy of said array and not the array itself; thus, resulting in a delay. I think I have to use ArrayBuffer or SharedArrayBuffer but it's not clear how I can convert my array of objects into an ArrayBuffer and then convert it back

Comment: Questions about code here should include the code you've currently using and then you should ask a specific question about that code that you need help with.  Abstract questions that read more like "please write this code for me" are not often answered here.  We expect you to research the topic, follow some examples, attempt to write the code and then if you get stuck, you show the code and ask a specific question about where you got stuck.  Your question includes NO code so it doesn't show evidence of you doing any of the previous steps.

Comment: @jfriend00 added my code; although, I don't think it makes a difference...

Comment: And, what exactly is the problem with this code that you need help with?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to pass each segment to a worker thread by reference and not by copying it. I cannot figure out how to pass an array of JSON objects to a worker without it being copied.

Furthermore, I'm not sure how I would set up workers in such a way so that I can run jest tests with each segment

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to share objects without copying.  You can use an array in shared memory and pass a reference to that, but it has to be an array of primitive values, not an array of objects.  I'd suggest reading the second answer here [Share objects in nodejs between different instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519325/share-objects-in-nodejs-between-different-instances).

Comment: What is the problem with copying the objects?  If it's total memory use, then just feed the worker 100 objects at a time and let it crunch on those and when done, get another 100.  Then, you don't have high peak memory use because the copies are only temporal.

Comment: Another possibility is described here: [Nodejs worker threads shared object store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053222/node-js-worker-threads-shared-object-store).

Comment: @jfriend00 the main problem is speed. With such a large number of data (~4GB) whenever it gets copied it slows down the whole process. 
Anyways thanks a lot for bearing with me and redirecting me to that thread!

Comment: Maybe the data belongs in redis where you can query data as needed form each worker?  Or convert smaller pieces of data at a time where there won't be one giant long pause as that conversion time will be broken up into much smaller pieces.